# Approach to unlock content in Django after a successful payment

Tags: django, payment

I have something like ‚Requests to Offers‘ model in my homepage. A user can create a request, and other users can offer content to this specific request. After the requesting user has accepted a offer and the payment was done, the content should be unlocked / downloadable.

I thought about creating a transaction model with ‚Requests, Offers, State‘

After the payment was done, the State should change to „Active“ which results in an active „Download“ Button.

Is this an approach you would recommend (fairly new to Django) or are there other ways to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking in right direction. But it would be good if you could show your models, cause it's quite difficult to plan your architecture, as always there can be additional business logic. Just a scratch to start:

A content model that user can offer

```
class Content(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.RichTextField()
```

Request model. Users can create requests that can be seen by other users.

```
class Request(models.Model):
    requestor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Any user can respond to request with offer if he has content (it can be content content with special type only, idk):

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'pending'
    WAITING_FOR_PAYMENT = 'waiting_for_payment'
    PAYMENT_COMPLETE = 'payment_complete'
    DECLINED = 'declined'
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, _('Pending')),
        (WAITING_FOR_PAYMENT, _('Waiting for payment'),
        (PAYMENT_COMPLETE, _('Payment complete')),
        (DECLINED, _('Declined')),
    )

    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.Charfield(max_length=32, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
```

You can manage offer's state. For example, if `state=PAYMENT_COMPLETE` you can show download link to content, etc.

As I said above it's impossible to predict schema without specs. I suggest you just to start coding.

Comment: Hi Satevg, I already have the models done, just the "Offer" class is missing. I was curious If I am going to the right direction here. Thank you for your Input!